# How to remove space at the end of a cab abbreviation and wait for input in GVim?

Tags: vim, abbreviation

I have created a Vim abbreviation for the start of a file path, i.e.

```
cab  \x\     M:\xmlexport\Output\
```

and I want to have this expand, remove the space and wait for further input. I have tried using `=Eatchar('s')` but don't know what to put before it to make it trigger correctly. All the examples I have seen use `<C-R>` which adds in a new line. I have tried `<left>` just to move back one space but this creates `M:\xmlexport\Output \`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but I've tested the function you pointed out and seems to work:

I've added the `Eatchar` function to `.vimrc`:

```
func Eatchar(pat)
   let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
   return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c                                                                                    
endfunc
```

And inside `vim` I've created your abbreviation, like:

```
:cab  \x\     M:\xmlexport\Output\ <left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```

Then I write `:\x\` in command-line and it expands to `:M:\xmlexport\Output\`, and the cursor position is just after the last backslash to write your desired input.

Comment: Having looked again today it does now seem to work. I made some other alterations to my vimrc this morning, I am guessing I had a conflict in there with something!